# A custom xml animation resource which is a copy of the Android xml animation resource does not behave identically

Tags: xml, animation, resources

I am new to developing for Android.  I have developed for IOS for a while.
I wanted to set up an animated transition between two activities, a main and an about activity which slid in from the right on opening then slid out to the right on closing - pretty basic stuff.  The only way that seemed to work was to call overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right) directly after startActivity(..) but this does not allow the reverse animation as there are no corresponding android.R.anim.slide_in_right and android.R.anim.slide_out_left resources.  I thought I would create my own.  As a start I created an XML resource file named enter_left.xml which was simply copied from the definition android.R.anim.slide_in_left.  I then used this as the first argument to override..(R.anim.enter_left.xml,..) expecting an identical result.  It was not.  Now I am confused and have a headache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course the real problem was that changes in xml animation descriptions are not reflected in the compiled APK when instant run is selected as an option.  Switch it off and everything works as expected.  Google are still developing this and I note are asking for problem reports on instant run so I will let then know.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I found out the issue.  It took ages.  Basically changes in the xml description of an animation are not applied when you re-run the app!  I found the only reliable way on the simulator was to stop and restart it then run the app.  Developing on a real phone was slightly easier in that I only had to kill the app forcing a reinstall of the APK.  I suppose this might be an animation caching issue.  Basically its a bug in the ADS.